# mySql query giving result in wrong order

Tags: mysql

I am using this mysql query to fetch data from DB

```
 SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT( streetObj.street_type, ' ',streetObj.street_name, ', ', neighborhoodObj.name , ', ', cityObj.name, ', ', stateObj.abbreviation ) namet 
            FROM street streetObj 
            LEFT 
            JOIN cep cepObj1 
              ON cepObj1.street_id = streetObj.street_id 
            LEFT 
            JOIN neighborhood neighborhoodObj 
              ON neighborhoodObj.neighborhood_id = cepObj1.start_neighborhood_id 
            LEFT 
            JOIN city cityObj 
              ON streetObj.city_id = cityObj.city_id 
            LEFT 
            JOIN state stateObj 
              ON stateObj.state_id = cityObj.state_id 
           WHERE CONCAT(streetObj.street_type,streetObj.street_name) LIKE '%rua%' 
             AND CONCAT(streetObj.street_type,streetObj.street_name) LIKE '%Gomes%' 
             AND CONCAT(streetObj.street_type,streetObj.street_name) LIKE '%de%' 
             AND CONCAT(streetObj.street_type,streetObj.street_name) like '%Ca%' 
             AND cityObj.city_id = '9668' 
           ORDER 
              BY namet ASC 
           LIMIT 10;
```

This query is executed when I type

```
 rua Gomes de Ca
```

And this query result is this

```
 Rua Baltazar Gomes de Alarcão, Jardim Miriam, São ...
 Rua Cabo José Gomes de Barros, Conjunto Habitacion...
 Rua Cabo Luís Gomes de Quevedo, Parque Novo Mundo,...
 Rua Gomes de Carvalho, Vila Olímpia, São Paulo, SP
 Rua João Gomes de Mendonça, Jaraguá, São Paulo, SP
 Rua João Gomes de Mendonça, Jardim Taipas, São Pau...
 Rua Pedro Gomes de Camargo, Vila Rio Branco, São P...
```

So as you can see i want those results on top which find exact match, But its not working.
In this query i want

```
   Rua Gomes de Carvalho, Vila Olímpia, São Paulo, SP
```

on top position.

Comment: Aliases that are longer than the table name. Nice idea.

Comment: @renu, to clarify, strawberry was being sarcastic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rank the results by the strength of the match, and sort by that.  You will have to define the sort yourself. For example:

```
select ..
from...
ORDER BY
case 
when text like "%all my search phrase%" then 1
when text like "%all my%" then 2
when text like "%search phrase%" then 2
when text like "%phrase%" then 3
else 1000 end
DESCENDING
```

or

```
ORDER BY
case when text like "%word%" then 1 else 0 end
+
case when text like "%second_word%" then 1 else 0 end
+
.....
DESC
```

Specifically for your example

```
select namet from
    (select 'Rua Baltazar Gomes de Alarcão, Jardim Miriam, São ...' as namet 
    union all select 'Rua Cabo José Gomes de Barros, Conjunto Habitacion...'
    union all select 'Rua Cabo Luís Gomes de Quevedo, Parque Novo Mundo,...'
    union all select 'Rua Gomes de Carvalho, Vila Olímpia, São Paulo, SP'
    union all select 'Rua João Gomes de Mendonça, Jaraguá, São Paulo, SP'
    union all select 'Rua João Gomes de Mendonça, Jardim Taipas, São Pau...'
    union all select 'Rua Pedro Gomes de Camargo, Vila Rio Branco, São P...')tbl
order by 
case when namet like "%rua gomes de ca%" then 100 else 0 end+ #high score for full match
case when namet like "%rua%" then 1 else 0 end+ #lower score for partial matches
case when namet like "%Gomes%" then 1 else 0 end+
case when namet like "%de%" then 1 else 0 end+
case when namet like "%ca%" then 1 else 0 end desc LIMIT 10
```

Although you probably want to write something to split your search phrase into words, search for every word, and rank on number of words matched. You could also look into soundex or levenstein distance for ranking similarity. Doing it in sql though is harder than doing it programatically.

Comment: You should sort descending. I tried the below and it worked

select product_name from table o
order by 
case when product_name like "%w1%" then 1 else 0 end
+ case when product_name like "%w2%" then 1 else 0 end
+ case when product_name like "%w3%" then 1 else 0 end
desc 
limit 10

Comment: Sorry, but i tried both, asc and desc, Not working for both.

Comment: Works fine, I think the issue you are encountering is that you need to put thought into HOW to rank your matches. The technical part is answered. The query works and the concept is solid, but you need to actually work with it and think it through, and not copy paste an example sort from stack. See my edit above. Stack is for asking questions on how to fix issues, not for doing all the work.